# Fixing the '\social' command of 'moderncv' for LinkedIN (intl profile)

Tags: moderncv

I am using `moderncv` to compose my CV and cover letters.
I have a [LinkedIN profile](http://it.linkedin.com/pub/stefano-bragaglia/51/22/b43/) that I would like to link via

```
\social[linkedin]{...}
```

however line 257 of `modencv.cls` defaults the beginning of the link to `www.linkedin.com/in/`:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
```

In my case, instead, the prefix and the suffix are respectively `www.linkedin.com/pub/` and `stefano-bragaglia/51/22/b43/` (instead of `stefano.bragaglia`, as suggested by the template).

In practice the base link should be changed in `www.linkedin.com/` and the 2nd parameter of `\social` should be modified in `pub/stefano-bragaglia/51/22/b43/`.
At the moment I have created a copy of `moderncv` with the appropriate changes in my local repository, but I wonder whether it is better to include an appropriate `\renewcommand` (or similar) in the preamble of the file (what should I write) or just notify the author and ask for a fix.

If you need a *minimal working example*, just use the [default template](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) of `moderncv`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's better if you provide a MWE here.

Comment: You can customize your profile URL: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/87 After doing that, it will become of the form www.linkedin.com/in/xxx where you can choose xxx

Comment: It only works if you have a nominal url (something like linkedin.com/in/______) but not with standard urls (i.e.: linkedin.com/pub/____-____/dd/dd/wdd). Moreover, if you have a localised linkedin (i.e.: linkedin.it/pub/ etc etc) it won't work as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think, in this case, you don't really need any redefinitions; the author/maintainer of `moderncv` has provided a second optional argument for `\social` that can be used, for example, in cases in which the prefixes/suffixes are different from the ones provided by default (when this second argument is not used). In this concrete case, you could say

```
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/pub/stefano-bragaglia/51/22/b43/]{stefano-bragaglia}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/pub/stefano-bragaglia/51/22/b43/]{stefano-bragaglia}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting httplink and its associated address:

[image]

Some of the LinkedIn adresses have /in, some others /pub, so I guess the maintainer chose one by default, and provided the second optional argument for the other cases.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo, amazing! Thanks for the explanation! By the way, where is the documentation for the class? I wasn't able to find on CTAN... my fault?

Comment: @StefanoBragaglia Hi! You're welcome! No, it's not your fault; `moderncv` still doesn't have a user documentation, besides the information you find in the templates. Unfortunately, some features are not mentioned there (this second optional argument for `\social`, for example). I had to go to the definitions in `moderncv.cls` to find out about this possibility.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina hello, does it work for twitter, github also ? Like 
`\social[twitter][www.twitter.com/]{stefano-bragaglia}`
`\social[github][www.github.com/sb.git]{stefano-bragaglia}`

Comment: I added twitter using the following line (I had to escape the '_'): `\social[twitter][twitter.com/bioinfo_mark]{@bioinfo\_mark}`

Comment: is there any trick to add them all in one line separated with `|` for instance?