# LinkedIn logo in Latex

Tags: logos

How could I get a LinkedIn logo (like those found in http://press.linkedin.com/Media-Resources?SubjectID=644) in Latex?

I found some tikz code somewhere, but that was not for one in blue, and it didn't look quite the same.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Why not just include one of those as a graphic?

Comment: @Thruston I want to use it in a cv, as a logo. I don't know if There would be a handy way to get the image neatly in the header that way. But if there is then that would be nice :)

Comment: Just `\usepackage{graphicx}` then `\includegraphics{logo_file}` where you need it.

Comment: Of course if you posted an example of what you where trying to do, people might be able to suggest improvements.

Comment: Also see [LinkedIn Branding Guidelines](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/branding-guidelines#general-use)...

Comment: The guidelines Werner links to make it fairly clear that you should include one of the supplied images rather than try to emulate the logo with typeset text.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) provides a number of "Social icons":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing% Just for this example
\verb|Facebook|: \faFacebook \quad \faFacebookSquare \par
\verb|Twitter|: \faTwitter \quad \faTwitterSquare \par
\verb|Github|: \faGithub \quad \faGithubSquare \par
\verb|HTML5|: \faHtml5 \par
\verb|LinkedIn|: \faLinkedin \quad \faLinkedinSquare \par
\verb|Pinterest|: \faPinterest \quad \faPinterestSquare \par
\verb|Google+|: \faGooglePlus \quad \faGooglePlusSquare
\end{document}
```

It requires compilation via XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

---

Following the discussion on [LinkedIn Branding Guidelines](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/branding-guidelines#general-use), you can also [download the EPS versions](http://press.linkedin.com/search/Media-Resources?SearchText=eps) of the LinkedIn logo and include them using `\includegraphics` (from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)).

Comment: Very nice. Would there be a way though to get the original, blue linkedin icon?

Comment: @rbm: Add the [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to your preamble (`\usepackage{xcolor}`) and use `\colorLinkedinSign` where `\newcommand{\colorLinkedinSign}{\textcolor{rgb:red,6;green,108;blue,170}{\faLinkedinSign}}`. [This is the output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HyLMT.png).

Comment: Whops!! `academicons` for ResearchGate, Google Scholar, pubMed, OrcID, Zotero, etc. https://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/

Answer (score 14):

Also trusting various websites and having Adobe Myriad Pro Bold on your system,

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro Bold}

\begin{document}
Linked\tikz[baseline=(i.text)]\node[fill=blue,rounded corners=0.25ex,text=white,inner sep=0.3ex](i) {in};

\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't try to match the roundedness, kern or any other detail but if you wish you can do some precision surgery on it.

Comment: Oops, I forgot again that this needs LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: Also pdfLaTeX if you have the `MyriadPro` package installed.

Comment: @Manuel That's a very tricky thing in terms of copyright issues because the font exclusively belongs to Adobe and it is not released for free usage. Do you have a recent version somewhere? Or you mean `mdsymbol` ?

Comment: @percusse That may be true (I know nothing about copyright), but there is a package, and a script to convert the .otf to .pfb and .afm to be used with pdfLaTeX. My point was that there is an available Myriad Pro for non-(Xe/Lua)TeX.

Comment: @Manuel Yes but it's not on CTAN (cannot be) that's why I asked. Where did you get it?

Comment: @percusse Well. First thing: I downloaded long time ago both of them from a [GitHub](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/) page. Later I've seen MinionPro [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/). So I thought Myriad was also on CTAN, but it's not true, as you say.

Answer (score 10):

I think the simplest path is to use the EPS logos provided.  With `pdflatex` you will have to convert the EPS file to PDF, but there are many ways to do that (see [What are good ways to convert EPS to PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2872/1402)) including “automatically” as in my installation.  If you download the [LinkedIn logo “bug” as EPS](https://brand.linkedin.com/downloads), you get a file `LinkedIn-InBug-2C.eps`.  Then use something like this document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/190927/1402
\begin{document}
\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\includegraphics[width=2.5ex]{LinkedIn-InBug-2C}}%
linked.in/johndoe
\end{document}
```

and you get this:

[image: sample code output]

I had to manually adjust the `width` and `\raisebox` arguments to get the size and vertical placement right.  There might be other ways.

Answer (score 1):

For `\documentclass[...]{moderncv}` I find very useful information here: 
[Fixing the '\social' command of 'moderncv' for LinkedIN (intl profile)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/fixing-the-social-command-of-moderncv-for-linkedin-intl-profile)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on @Werner's answer, hence I make it an answer.

As of 2021, being on Mac OS X using a current MacTex Version, one has to use `fontawesome5` instead of the `fontawesome` package to avoid the errors documented here: [FontAwesome font not found?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found)

Therefore, the code of @Werner's answer can be adapted as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing% Just for this example
\verb|Facebook|: \faFacebook \quad \faFacebookSquare \par
\verb|Twitter|: \faTwitter \quad \faTwitterSquare \par
\verb|Github|: \faGithub \quad \faGithubSquare \par
\verb|HTML5|: \faHtml5 \par
\verb|LinkedIn|: \faLinkedin \quad \faLinkedinSquare \par
\verb|Pinterest|: \faPinterest \quad \faPinterestSquare \par
\verb|Google+|: \faGooglePlus \quad \faGooglePlusSquare
\end{document}
```