# FontAwesome is not working in Friggeri resume?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, cv, friggeri-cv

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{FontAwesome}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}
\definecolor{html5}{HTML}{e34c26}
\definecolor{php}{HTML}{6c7eb7}
\definecolor{db}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1683BB}


\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}
% \addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\header{Kiker}{Surname}{Front End Web Developer} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{contact}
{\color{light-gray}{\FA \faHome}}
{\color{skype}{\FA \faSkype}} \href{skype:myskype.myskype?call}{myskype.myskype}
{\color{light-gray}{\FA \faEnvelope}} \href{mailto:myemail@gmail.com}{myemail@gmail.com}
~
{\color{html5}{\FA \faFire}} \href{http://www.mywebsite.de}{Portfolio}
{\color{gray}{\FA \faPencil}} \href{http://www.myblog.net}{My Blog}
{\color{linkedin}{\FA \faLinkedin}} \href{http://au.linkedin.com/pub/}{LinkedIn}
{\color{gray}{\FA \faGithubSign}} \href{https://github.com/}{GitHub}
\section{programming}
\small{{\color{red} \FA \faHeart} JavaScript, jQuery,
{\color{html5}\FA \faHtml5} HTML5, CSS3,
{\color{php}\FA \faCode} PHP, Groovy/Grails,
{\color{gray}\FA \faLinux} Linux, LEMP, NGINX,
{\color{db}\FA \faTh} MySQL, Amazon AWS}
 \section{languages}
 \emph{proficient} English
 \emph{mother tongue} Italian
 \emph{notions} Spanish \& French
\end{aside}

\section{{\FA \faUser} About me}

\section{{\FA \faStar} Expertise}

\textbf{Professional Capabilities}
\begin{itemize}
    \item{High-quality front-end development for web sites and applications}
    \item{Modular, DRY, robust and reusable code}
    \item{Performance optimization, progressive enhancement, usability}
    \item{SEO with semantic HTML, Micro Formats and schema.org structures}
    \item{Site planning}
    \item{User interface design}
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Technical Skills}
\begin{itemize}
    \item{Scalable HTML and CSS}
    \item{JavaScript Development (includes advanced jQuery and plugins development, HTML5 API, vanilla JavaScript)}
    \item{Responsive Web Design}
    \item{Mobile development (in browser)}
    \item{Experience with Linux environments.}
    \item{Working knowledge of PHP, using: CodeIgniter, ExpressionEngine, WordPress}
    \item{Experience with Groovy/Grails}
    \item{Working experience with software versioning, in particular Git and Mercurial}
    \item{CSS Preprocessor (SASS, SCSS and LESS)}
\end{itemize}

\clearpage
\section{{\FA \faSuitCase} Experience}

\section{{\FA \faBook} Education}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
{2004--2010}
{Degree in {\normalfont Computer Science and Automation Engineering}}
{Polytechnic Marche University, Italy}
{  }

\end{entrylist}


\section{{\FA \faQuote} Recommandations}


\end{document}
```

Specially for Skype, Facebook, Linken is working in this code?

Comment: [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) from CTAN doesn't have `\faSkype`, `\faLinux`, `\faTh` nor `\faQuote`; `\faSuitCase` should be `\faSuitcase`; and [`\faHtml5` should be `\faHTMLfive`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/190931/5764).

Answer (score 4):

You can use these icons (that are part ot the font since version 4) with this code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\def\faSkype{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}
\def\faLinux{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}
\def\faTh{\FA\symbol{"F00A}}
\def\faQuoteLeft{\FA\symbol{"F10D}}
\def\faQuoteRight{\FA\symbol{"F10E}}

\begin{document}

Here are missing symbols in the \emph{Fontawesome} package:

\begin{center}\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}\renewcommand\tabcolsep{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\verb+\faSkype+ &\verb+\faLinux+ &\verb+\faTh+ &\verb+\faQuoteLeft+ &\verb+\faQuoteRight+\\
{\color{CadetBlue1}\faSkype}  &  \faLinux  &  \faTh  &  \faQuoteLeft  &  \faQuoteRight
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get the last version of the font [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/whats-new/). As far as Xe(Lua)LaTeX is concerned, only the `.otf` font file is useful. You can install it either on your system, or in `temf-local\fonts\otf\fontawesome`.

Comment: still it's not working. Skype and Linux icon is not showing

Comment: Do you have installed `last version` (4.1) of the `.otf` font file themselves on your system or on your `local` texmf tree. In the latter case did you run `texhash` (TeX Live)  or `refresh FNDB` (MiKTeX)? Last, did you try with a basic document and a standard class (one never knows…)?

Comment: Yea I download it and install the Fontawesome. I am using the Winedt not TeXLive. Skype and Linux is not working

Comment: Did you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Yes, at XeLaTeX is working but not showing the icons and on LuaLaTeX is given error Minion Pro is not founnd

Comment: Try first with a basic document, load fontspec and write in the preamble `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15773/discussion-between-bernard-and-latexkhan).

Comment: @Bernad in chat room