# Want to add the Skype and LinkedIn Icon on the left side of Friggeri Resume?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, luatex, cv, friggeri-cv

```
\documentclass[]{myfriggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}
\definecolor{html5}{HTML}{e34c26}
\definecolor{php}{HTML}{6c7eb7}
\definecolor{db}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1683BB}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\header{First Name}{Last Name}{Name of Profession} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{personal info}
\emph{D.O.B}
\emph{Nationality} Pakistani
\emph{Marital status}
\section{{\FA \faHome}}
~
\section{\faPhone}
%+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\section{\faEnvelope}
{abcd@outlook.com}
%\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
%\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
\emph{proficient} English
\emph{mother tongue}  Urdu
\section{computer literacy}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} MS-Office
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Objective SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{objective}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013 - Now}
{Name od Employer}
{City, Country}
{\emph{Job Responsibility} \\
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}}
\end{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2011}
{Masters {\normalfont in Business Administration}}
{Name of University, City}
{Specialization in Supply Chain Management}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2008}
{Bachelors {\normalfont in Business Administration}}
{Name of University, City}
{Specialization in Management}

%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{additional skills}
\section{references}
 %

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 \section{communication skills}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  INTERESTS SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\section{interests}   
%
%\textbf{professional:} data analysis, company profiling, risk analysis, economics, web design, web app creation, software design, marketing \textbf{personal:} piano, chess, cooking, dancing, running
%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  PUBLICATIONS SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you want them? What have you tried to get them there? Skype-symbo is contained in `fontawesome`. Don't know what "Linken" is.

Comment: How does your new question differ from this old one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191648/fontawesome-is-not-working-in-friggeri-resume ??? And why it is tagged with `tikz-pgf`?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: "LinkedIn" perhaps?

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: A similar question by you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191683/want-to-add-the-different-icons‌​-in-friggeri-resume-like-email-phone-mobile-sk, also possibly a duplicate

Comment: @LaTeXKhan You are really not meeting the style of our side here. All your questions contain almost no explanations, non-minimal codes and start with "Want to this.." or "Want to that...". This is not about getting work done by others here but about unsalaried people helping others. On a question like this I can only recommend http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19553

Comment: @LaRiFari: How did you find that link? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes yesterday i post the above question but nobody can't guide properly about my problem.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Ok Next time i will try to explain my question properly.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: Well, `properly` is relative. Well defined questions tend to be answered quickly and `properly` ;-)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi in fontawesome is not contained the skype icon. I read the fontawesome text file.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I refrain from looking about such questions nowadays

Comment: @LaTeXKhan What happened to [your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191648) here? This was exactly about your topic. Do you have the new font? Can you use xe- or lua?

Comment: I used the both  xe-lua but skype icon is not working. But other icon is working \faHome, \faPhone etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logos can be found on the internet. You can then insert the logos using the includegraphics command.

```
\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{linkedinLogo.png}}
{linkedin.com/in/yourname}
~
\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{skypeLogo.png}}
{skype:yourname?call}
~
```

Another possibility is to draw the logos using Tikz. I have created the LinkedIN logo in myFriggeri_cv.sty like this:

```
\definecolor{linkedinblue}{RGB}{0,122,180}

\newcommand{\linkedInLogoTikz}[1]{
\scalebox{#1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.05pt, x=0.05pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]

  %background square
    \fill[linkedinblue, nonzero rule,rounded corners=5] (19.0,69.4)
  rectangle (724.4,774.8);

    %Draw 'n'
  \path[fill=white] (399.9674,578.3622) ..
    controls (400.6,477.8) and (400.7,475.2) .. (405.9,458.4) ..
    controls (413.8,432.5) and (431.9,419.8) .. (461.0,419.8) ..
    controls (491.6,419.7) and (505.9,432.7) .. (512.5,466.4) ..
    controls (514.1,474.4) and (514.3,485.5) .. (514.8,573.9) --
    (515.4,672.4) -- (567.7,672.6) .. controls (606.7,672.8) and
    (620.5,672.6) .. (621.5,671.7) .. controls (622.8,670.7) and
    (622.9,654.4) .. (622.6,559.9) .. controls (622.2,439.6) and
    (622.2,440.6) .. (616.2,413.9) .. controls (603.1,355.2) and
    (567.5,326.8) .. (503.9,324.2) .. controls (474.9,323.0) and
    (451.8,328.6) .. (430.0,342.1) .. controls (420.6,347.9) and
    (404.1,363.5) .. (399.9,370.6) .. controls (398.5,372.9) and
    (397.0,374.8) .. (396.6,374.8) .. controls (396.2,374.9) and
    (395.9,365.7) .. (395.9,354.6) .. controls (395.9,340.1) and
    (395.5,333.9) .. (394.7,333.1) .. controls (393.8,332.2) and
    (381.2,331.9) .. (344.2,331.9) .. controls (300.8,331.9) and
    (294.8,332.0) .. (293.4,333.4) .. controls (292.0,334.8) and
    (291.6,351.5) .. (291.9,502.0) .. controls (291.9,615.7) and
    (292.2,669.6) .. (292.9,670.9) .. controls (293.9,672.8) and
    (295.3,672.9) .. (346.6,672.6) -- (399.4,672.4) -- cycle;

  % dot over i
        \fill[white] (175,227) circle (63);
  % i rectangle
        \fill[white] (121.5,332.8) rectangle (229.6,670.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
```

It can then be inserter in the same way as the other sections:

```
\section{\linkedInLogoTikz{0.4}}
{linkedin.com/in/yourname}
~
```

The result:
[image]

The complete example:

```
\documentclass[]{myfriggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}
\definecolor{html5}{HTML}{e34c26}
\definecolor{php}{HTML}{6c7eb7}
\definecolor{db}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1683BB}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\header{First Name}{Last Name}{Name of Profession} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{personal info}
\emph{D.O.B}
\emph{Nationality} Pakistani
\emph{Marital status}
\section{{\FA \faHome}}
~
\section{\faPhone}
%+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{linkedinLogo.png}} %or \section{\linkedInLogoTikz{0.4}}
{linkedin.com/in/yourname}
~
\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{skypeLogo.png}}
{skype:yourname?call}
~
\section{\faEnvelope}
{abcd@outlook.com}
%\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
%\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
\emph{proficient} English
\emph{mother tongue}  Urdu
\section{computer literacy}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} MS-Office
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Objective SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{objective}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013 - Now}
{Name od Employer}
{City, Country}
{\emph{Job Responsibility} \\
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}}
\end{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2011}
{Masters {\normalfont in Business Administration}}
{Name of University, City}
{Specialization in Supply Chain Management}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2008}
{Bachelors {\normalfont in Business Administration}}
{Name of University, City}
{Specialization in Management}

%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{additional skills}
\section{references}
 %

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 \section{communication skills}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  INTERESTS SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\section{interests}   
%
%\textbf{professional:} data analysis, company profiling, risk analysis, economics, web design, web app creation, software design, marketing \textbf{personal:} piano, chess, cooking, dancing, running
%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  PUBLICATIONS SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post the whole example instead of a fragment. Welcome to TeX.SX. anyway

Comment: @MadsDyrmann Thanks. It is possible to modified the friggeri-cv.cls where i define these icons/symbols.