# Is there an equivalent for \Latex{} for Github and Twitter?

Tags: logos, fontawesome

So I'd like to have commands like `\LaTeX` for Github and twitter, i.e. something like `\GitHub{}` and `\Twitter{}` that would print the names with the correct fonts, kerning, etc…

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, especially since in my initial attempts to reinvent the wheel I've struggled to even figure out what the correct font is.

I see ([this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/190931/70067)) that fontawesome has icons, but I'm looking for it to say "Twitter", not show a little bird.  Perhaps I've missed it if they've also set up something for the company name.

Comment: Hi, I tried to rewrite a bit your first sentence, to make it more meaningful (I think it was a bit unclear before). I hope not to have altered the meaning in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Twitter has an "official logo with font", but GitHub appears to be just Sans Serif, so something like:

```
\newcommand\GitHub{\textsf{GitHub}}
```

You might want to consider just using small-caps though, as an alternative:

```
\newcommand\Twitter{\textsc{Twitter}}
```

Comment: Here's a link with the twitter font (not going to show it since I don't know all the copyright issues involved): http://www.clipartkid.com/images/0/13-twitter-logo-vector-png-free-cliparts-that-you-can-download-to-you-f0BkHR-clipart.png