# How to include social's icons like gitHub and linkedin in ModernCv?

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I am using modernCv, classic style and I need to include my linkedIn and gitHub icons next to my account address in my cv.
None of the solutions mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190954/skype-icon-on-moderncv) nor [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/fixing-the-social-command-of-moderncv-for-linkedin-intl-profile) have worked for me.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Package/font `fontawesome` provides these symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faGithub, \faLinkedin,
\faStackExchange, and \faStackOverflow
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great! It works well!
How can I use a different display name for it? 
It won't work like this: \faGithub{real URL}{display-name}

Comment: Solved by this! 
\faGithub\href{real URL}{display-name}

Comment: I can't manage to use the `\faStackOverflow` on sharelatex even thought `\faGithub` does work. I'm using LuaLatex to compile. The error I get is the generic `Undefined control sequence`

Comment: @DiegoAgher The example works with the recent [CTAN version 4.6.3.2](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) (`fontawesome.sty` reports 4.6.3.1). Maybe, ShareLaTeX uses an older version. The ChangeLog of the documentation does not tell, which symbol was introduced in which version.

Comment: How could I add my credit in stackoverflow or math.SE in my CV in latex?

Answer (score 5):

In my case the linked solution did work for me (maybe your LaTeX distribution was too old?), so I'll mention it for people that arrive on this page. You can use the `\social` command already included in Moderncv. Taken from [this example](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template.tex) in the "manual":

```
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[xing]{john\_doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}
\social[skype]{jdoe}
```

You can also [customize the url](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/2033517d3f29f9c16af1b3421d52f281e94aa2a5/moderncv.cls#L258) using something like:

```
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/myname/]{My name}
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, add a new class file name 'moderncv.cls' and paste the code in the link
[https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncv.cls](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls)

If you want to add icon images then download the icon image from google search and upload on your project then find the line

```
\collectionnew{socials}
```

Then add the bellow code before it (as much copy as you needed)

```
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}~}
```

'example-image-a' is the corresponding image name.

Now use as follows -

```
\social[researchgate]{name}
\social[googlescholar]{id}
```

Comment: To add to this nice answer, one can send a link to their scholar page like this: \social[googlescholar][scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en\&user=ID]{ID}, where ID is the google scholar ID.

Answer (score 3):

Package `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` may seem to be the one of the best option for adding icons, but imagine a case icon's you wanted is not included in **fontawesome** package like in my case at least, I have to add icon's for several online coding platforms, in that situation you can use `\usepackage{graphicx}` package to add you own icons:

> ## Step 1: Add Icons in your project

[image]

> ## Step 2 Include package `\usepackage{graphicx}`

[image]

> ## Step 3 Add icon/image `\includegraphics[height=10pt,width=10pt]{file-name.ext}`

[image]

> ## Output:

[image]