# Is there a StackExchange Symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: logos

Is there a StackExchange logo in Latex (package)?

Something like this:

[image]

I have managed to find packages for similar [logos like LinkedIn, Facebook, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190927/linkedin-logo-in-latex). but couldn't find one for StackExchange?

Comment: Technically that's not the Stack Exchange icon. That's the SE menu *hamburger*. However, you can use [`fontawesome`](//ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome)'s `\faStackExchange`, as suggested in [How to include social's icons like gitHub and LinkedIn in `moderncv`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338657/5764)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: Apologies - I must have missed those links! Sorry! I'll delete the question!

Comment: @3kstc No need to delete; it's been marked as duplicate and in fact it's arguably better to keep this question around so that anyone who searches for this can find this one and thereby be led to the other questions.