# Trouble producing StackOverflow icon with ModernCV

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I'm attempting to use ModernCV's `\social` tool with the stackoverflow logo.

Following [this advise](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591880/109006), I uploaded this version of moderncv.cls to my project: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls.

I added the [stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4O9t.jpg) logo to my project as a jpg image title `SO.jpg`.

I've tried adding the following to line 270 of the cls file, right before the line that says `\collectionnew{socials}`:

`\newcommand*{\stackoverflowsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.33cm]{SO.jpg}~}`

I've also tried replacing line 335, which originally has `\newcommand*{\stackoverflowsocialsymbol}{}` to `\newcommand*{\stackoverflowsocialsymbol}  {\includegraphics[width=0.33cm]{SO.jpg}~}`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm working Overleaf.

Here is my example tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{black} 


\firstname{kilo} 
\familyname{Joules} 


\social[linkedin]{kilojoules}           

\social[stackoverflow][stackoverflow.com/users/3474956/kilojoules]{kilojoules}   


\begin{document}


\makecvtitle 

The LinkedIn icon shows up fine, but the StackOverflow icon is missing.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: are there any compilation errors?

Comment: @WillieWong When I compile with the baseline cls file, there are no errors. When I do the first approach I describe (defining stackoverflowsocialsymbol immediately before line 270) , there is an error: `\stackoverflowsocialsymbol already defined`. When I do the second approach, replacing the definition of `stackoverflowsocialsymbol` on line 332, there are no errors. In all cases, the stackoverflow symbol does not appear.

Comment: I don't know why you are mucking around with editing the class file yourself; testing on Overleaf just now and the bundled `moderncv` already has the stackoverflow symbol included.

Comment: This is with `Document Class: moderncv 2021-07-28 v2.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class`, built using `TeXLive 2021` as the distribution of choice on Overleaf.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for looking into this. Could you post the successful tex file as an answer? My tex file does not work when I compile it with overleaf. In my real problem, I am also hoping to include a icon/link to my google scholar.

Comment: Wait, I think I see the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Work-around**: In Overleaf, please change the "compiler" to "XeLaTeX". (Do so by clicking on the Overleaf Menu on the top left corner and change the selection under "Settings".)

`moderncv` includes built-in symbols for *both* StackOverflow *and* GoogleScholar, via the `fontawesome5` and `academicons` packages, if you compile using LuaTex or XeTeX. (Side note: `fontawesome5` works fine with pdflatex too, but `academicons` do require Xe/LuaTeX.)

If you compile using pdfLatex, unfortunately, it uses a different method for defining icons (see the `moderncviconsmarvosym.sty` file). For LinkedIn a rendering of the LinkedIn icon is included in that file as a Tikz drawing, but no analogue of SO or GoogleScholar can be found in that file.

---

The reason that editing the .cls file doesn't do jack squat is because for the built-in symbols they are `\renewcommand`ed later on in the load process (when you issue `\moderncvstyle{...}`), so changing the definition in `moderncv.cls` doesn't help (as they get rewritten in `moderncviconsmarvosym.sty`).

If you want to use pdflatex, you should actually include the line

```
\renewcommand*{\stackoverflowsocialsymbol}{\includegraphics[width=0.33cm]{SO.jpg}~}
```

in the *Preamble* of your `.tex` file, *after* you call `\moderncvstyle`. This way it will overwrite the built-in and use the jpeg image you downloaded.