# Customizing social media icon in moderncv

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I am writing a moderncv on Overleaf, using a template found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/moderncv-and-cover-letter-template/sttkgjcysttn). I want to add a custom social media icon, and I am following the instructions from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591880).

I created a 'modercv.cls' file and pasted the provided code there. I have also uploaded an image named 'scholar_google_logo.png' and added the suggested code before the `\collectionnew{socials}` line:

```
\newcommand*{\googlescholarsocialsymbol}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{scholar_google_logo.png}~}
\collectionnew{socials}
```

The modification worked smoothly, and you can see the result in the attached image. However, I encountered a small issue where the scholar_id doesn't align perfectly at the center of the logo. Is there a way to adjust its position and raise it upward?

Furthermore, I tried to change the orchid logo in a similar manner:

```
\newcommand*{\orcidsocialsymbol}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{orcidlogo.png}~}
```

Unfortunately, this change didn't produce the desired outcome, as the output still displays a small old logo.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving these issues. Thank you for your help in advance.
[image]