# How to change moderncv \social[linkedin] from http to https?

Tags: moderncv, hyperlink

Hello I am new to LaTeX and like it!

In `moderncv` I have a Link to my Linkedin profile. However, this link is `http` and I'd like to change to `https`.

Example

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
    \moderncvstyle{casual}
    \moderncvcolor{blue}
    \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

    \name{John}{Doe}
    \social[linkedin]{reidhoffman}

    \begin{document}

    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}                        {Description}

    \end{document}
```

I tried to customize the link as described in [Fixing the '\social' command of 'moderncv' for LinkedIN (intl profile)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/fixing-the-social-command-of-moderncv-for-linkedin-intl-profile) but it doesn't accept https.

If you need a minimal working example, just use the default template of `moderncv` at http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix by "renew-ing" the documentclass command to use `\href{}{}` for 
this page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% Added these lines (until `\makeatother` that belongs to documentclass `moderncv.cls`)
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%NEXT LINE CHANGED FROM ORIGINAL
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/#3}{#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother
    \name{John}{Doe}
    \social[linkedin]{reidhoffman}


    \begin{document}

    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}                        {Description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @nemu Welcome... You nay accept the answer if it solves your problem (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer?s=2|38.3857)

Answer (score 2):

You need simply to define a new command `\httpslink` like

```
% makes a https hyperlink
% usage: \httpslink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{% <=======================================
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}
```

Then you can simply change the call of `\httplink` to `\httpslink` to get your wished result.

Please see the following MWE (important code changings marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% makes a https hyperlink
% usage: \httpslink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{% <=======================================
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}

% adds a social link to one's personal information (optional)
% usage: \social[<optional type>][<optional url>]{<account name>}
% where <optional type> should be either "linkedin", "twitter" or "github"
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{% <=============================
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}% <==========================================
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}% <=====================
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}% <=====================
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{#2}}}}


\name{John}{Doe}
\social[linkedin]{reidhoffman}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}                        {Description}

\end{document}
```

which gives you the wished result: `https://www.linkedin.com/in/reidhoffman`. Please see that I changed the old protocolls `httplink` to `httpslink` also for all other possibilitys command `\social` gave you to add social links to your cv ...