# Need help with the moderncv resume/cover letter template

Tags: moderncv, cv

I need help with this great template. It has both the resume and cover letter in one document but I'd like to make a few changes.

1. I'd like to add "job title" above summary and below email/phone in the resume. I was able to add this with some help. However, the "job title only shows on the cover letter. I'd like for it to show in the resume as well.
   [image]
2. I tried to center the "job title" using \centering but it didn't work. Any way to shift it to the center?
   [image]
3. The line spacing is a mess, it is not consistent throughout. Any way to make it consistent all over.
   [image]
4. This template has both the resume and cover letter in it. I was wondering if I could separate both the resume and cover letter into two separate documents. That way, I'll have both versions. It'll be easier to send documents that only require to send resume or cover letter.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.1}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{1111 Nowhere Street, Apt 111}{Nowhere, NW}{11111}
\phone[mobile]{(100)-111-1111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin][https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/]{john-doe}
\social[github][https://github.com/johndoe]{john-doe}

\Centering\title{Business Analysis | Data Analysis | Project Management | Information Systems} % <============================================
\moderncvhead{3}% <====================================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% <=================================================
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% <=============================
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% <==========================================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\begin{center}
\section{{Summary}}
\end{center}
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.  

\end{itemize} 

\begin{center}
\section{Technical Proficiency}
\end{center}
Advanced Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint), Visio, Project 2016, Alteryx, Tableau (Dashboards, Stories), Python, Java, R, SQL, PL/SQL, PostgreSQL, Mode, JIRA, SmartSheet, VirtualBox, Eclipse, WordPress, Adobe Photoshop

\begin{center}
\section{Areas of Expertise}
\end{center}
Business Analytics, Business Intelligence, Relationship Building, Predictive Modeling, Regression Analysis, Process Improvement, Project Management, Data Quality Management, User Acceptance Testing, Data Analysis, Visual Modeling
\begin{center}
\section{Professional Experience}
\end{center}
\cventry{Mar 2019--Present}{Research Assistant}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere}{}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\newline{}%
Key Contributions:%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\begin{center}
 \section{Academic Projects}
\end{center}
\cventry{Sept 2018--Dec 2018}{Nowhere Group Relocation}{Project Management}{}{}{\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Visualizing Movie Data}{Data Visualization}{}{}{\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Predicting Impact of New Menu}{A/B Testing}{}{}{\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Forecasting Video Game Sales}{Time-Series Forecasting}{}{}{\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{UMBeats DJ Club}{System Analysis and Design}{}{}{\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{Hotel Management System}{Database Application Management}{}{}{\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\begin{center}
   \section{Education}
\end{center}
\cventry{Jan 2013--Dec 2018}{Bachelor's of Science in Information Systems}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere, NW}{\textit{}}{}  
\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Business Analyst Nanodegree}{Udacity}{}{\textit{}}{}



\clearpage

\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{\today}
\opening{To The Hiring Manager,}
\closing{Respectfully Submitted,}

\makelettertitle

is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\begin{itemize}
    \item is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    \item is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    \item is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{itemize}

\makeletterclosing


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks for a code I can work with!

To your point 1, adding jobtitle to resume title and point 2, adding it centered:

You need to add a new patch to your code:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}% <===============================================
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    {\centering\textbf{\@title}\\[2em]}% <==============================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
```

That adds the job title after the complete resume title centered and printed boldface ...

To your point 3: different spaces after lines.

Well, that comes from your usage of environment `center` around your `\section{}` commands (please delete them in your code) and the way LaTeX tries to bring the last line of your cv on every page on the same place/line (to get rid of that use command `\raggedbottom`). At last you can use an option `[center]` to `moderncv` style `banking` to get all your sections printed centered above the line.

Please also note that I commented your added commands `\newline`

Please see the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[center]{banking} % <=====================================
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75, 
% top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.1}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{1111 Nowhere Street, Apt 111}{Nowhere, NW}{11111}
\phone[mobile]{(100)-111-1111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/]{john-doe}  % <===================
\social[github][github.com/johndoe]{john-doe}  % <=================

\title{Business Analysis | Data Analysis | Project Management | Information Systems} % <============================================
%\moderncvhead[center]{3}% <====================================== already called by banking
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% 
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% 
  }%
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}% <===============================================
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    {\centering\textbf{\@title}\\[2em]}% <==============================
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother

\raggedbottom % <=======================================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Summary}
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.  
\end{itemize} 

\section{Technical Proficiency}
Advanced Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint), Visio, Project 2016, Alteryx, Tableau (Dashboards, Stories), Python, Java, R, SQL, PL/SQL, PostgreSQL, Mode, JIRA, SmartSheet, VirtualBox, Eclipse, WordPress, Adobe Photoshop

\section{Areas of Expertise}
Business Analytics, Business Intelligence, Relationship Building, Predictive Modeling, Regression Analysis, Process Improvement, Project Management, Data Quality Management, User Acceptance Testing, Data Analysis, Visual Modeling

\section{Professional Experience}
\cventry{Mar 2019--Present}{Research Assistant}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere}{}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\newline{}%
Key Contributions:%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\section{Academic Projects}
\cventry{Sept 2018--Dec 2018}{Nowhere Group Relocation}{Project Management}{}{}%
{%\newline{}% <=========================================================
  \begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{itemize}%
}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Visualizing Movie Data}{Data Visualization}{}{}%
{%\newline{}% <=========================================================
  \begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{itemize}%
}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Predicting Impact of New Menu}{A/B Testing}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Forecasting Video Game Sales}{Time-Series Forecasting}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{UMBeats DJ Club}{System Analysis and Design}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{Hotel Management System}{Database Application Management}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\begin{center}
   \section{Education}
\end{center}
\cventry{Jan 2013--Dec 2018}{Bachelor's of Science in Information Systems}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere, NW}{\textit{}}{}  
\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Business Analyst Nanodegree}{Udacity}{}{\textit{}}{}



\clearpage

\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{\today}
\opening{To The Hiring Manager,}
\closing{Respectfully Submitted,}

\makelettertitle

is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\begin{itemize}
    \item is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
    \item is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    \item is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{itemize}

\makeletterclosing


\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please have a look to the bottom of page 1:

[image: result bottom first page]

As you can see marked with red arrow 1 there is a blank space resulting because the following text (seen on page two) can not fit the blank space above (it is to long for fitting into the blank space). Rephrase the text or add an `\clearpage` before the section ...

Same for `System Analysis and Design` at the end of page 2, to get it to the next page add `\clearpage` before ...

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to fix 1 and 2, and 3. I'd really appreciate it it's possible to separate resume and cover letter. Thank you again!

Comment: @Akboh You can divide cv and cover letter into two files. Copy your complete file `cv.tex` to `coverletter.tex`. Then delete the part for cover letter in file `cv.tex` and the part for cv in `coverletter.tex`. Voila!

Comment: You rock! Thank you so much @Mensch

Comment: Okay, one last question... The Linkedin and Github links don't work when I click on them. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Akboh Ups, I oversaw that, sorry. Change your code to `\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/]{john-doe}` (delete the `https://`) then you get working links in my pdf viewer but the disadvantage now is that class `moderncv` adds `http://` automaticaly. There is another answer of mine solving this issue, but I have to search for it ... When I found it I add an link here, okay?

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks again!

Comment: @Akboh Please see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423660/16550 and feel free to upvote it!